# how to convert date string from csv file into date format

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert String of anyformat into dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642175/convert-string-of-anyformat-into-dd-mm-yy-hhmmss-in-r)

Having date value in excel file is like `12/12/2010` I need to extract the date from the Excel file in `dd-mm-yyy hh:mm:ss` format. How can I do that in R?

When I tried using

```
strftime(as.POSIXct(as.Date(startdate)), format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="UCT")
```

to do this with the date `12/12/2000`,

```
I got the result like this: `0012-12-20 00:00:00`.
```

Thank you for your help.But i need to convert any date format into
 "dd-mm-yyyy hh mm ss".
that if i give any format of dates like - dd-mm-yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd any of these i need the resulted format in "dd-mm-yy hh mm ss"

Comment: You posted 3 almost identical questions in a short period. One has already be closed. This one should be as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
as.Date("12/31/2000", format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

which yields a [Date](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Dates.html) object, or:

```
d1 <- strptime("12/31/2000 17:35:17", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
class(d1)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
d1
[1] "2000-12-31 17:35:17"
```