# Convert String of anyformat into dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss in R

Tags: r

I am reading a date value from csv file.So the format will vary according to the date format of csv. How can I convert any date string to dd-mm-yyy  HH:mm:ss ?

**EDIT :**

The input format are :

```
dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd/mm/yyyy
dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd-mm-yyyy 

mm-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss
mm-dd-yyyy
mm/dd/yyyy

yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss
yyyy-mm-dd
```

I need to convert  all these formats to dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss

Comment: In general it will not be possible to accomplish that task since there will be many cases where `mm` and `dd` cannot be resolved on a case by case basis. It would be possible to address some of the other issues with `grepl` or `gegexpr`.

Answer (score 1):

See the `anytime` package whose `anytime` function does just that -- and *without requiring a format string*:

```
> inputs <- c("12/07/2017 10:11:12", "12/07/2017", "12-07-2017 10:11:12", 
+             "07-12-2017", "2017-12-07 10:11:12", "2017-12-07")
> library(anytime)
> anytime(inputs)
[1] "2017-12-07 10:11:12 CST" "2017-12-07 00:00:00 CST"
[3] "2017-12-07 10:11:12 CST" "2017-07-12 00:00:00 CDT"
[5] "2017-12-07 10:11:12 CST" "2017-12-07 00:00:00 CST"
>
```

*However*, your requirement of accepting *both* d-m-y and m-d-y is not satisfiable.  So *you* need to make a choice and supply an *explicit* format here.

In general, I highly recommend avoiding the ambiguity and sticking to y-m-d ISO formats.  As a convenience to stubborn North American habits, `anytime` and `anydata` also accept `m-d-y` ordering but it is dangerous.

Again, only you can tell if `3-4-5` is April 3rd or March 4th, and you need to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

`as.Date()` converts a string into a `Date` object. You will need to adapt its `format` parameter to the specific format your csv has.

Comment: I tried with as.Date() before .. The problem is I have to make it work in differnt places .So it should work with all format .

Comment: @user1790894, what do you mean "it should work with all format"? Can you share an example in your original question of the type of data you are working with?

Comment: the input format will vary according to the format of csv file that user used.So I need to convert the date in which ever format to dd-mm-yyy .

Comment: Do you have _any_ information at all, e.g., a set of possible formats? If so, you could try these and use the one that does not yield an error (with the `try()` function). Could you edit your question to give a few examples of date formats you could encounter?

Comment: I need to log off now, will try to look tonight if nobody else answers earlier. Note that dd/mm/yyy and mm/dd/yyyy may not be clearly identifiable - 10/12/2012 and 12/10/2012 can be validly interpreted either way.

Answer (score 0):

Try "lubridate" package. Here A_1.csv has both formats.

```
Data <-read.csv("Al_1.csv") # import data
str(Data)
a = NULL # create a null object
library(lubridate)
a$Date <- mdy_hm(Data$Date) # store dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss objects here
a$Price <- Data$Price # get respective values(it could by any other column)
b = NULL
b$Date <- mdy(Data$Date)
b$Price <- Data$Price

a <- as.data.frame(a)
b <- as.data.frame(b)


a <- a[is.na(a$Date)==FALSE,] # those with NA had diffrent formats remove it
b <- b[is.na(b$Date)==FALSE,]

b$Date <- as.POSIXlt(b$Date)# change your other format also to UTC


x <- rbind(a,b)
str(x)
x <- ts(x)
```

Comment: You may have missed that some input was `mdy` whereas other input was `dmy`.