# date conversion from any fromat

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert String of anyformat into dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642175/convert-string-of-anyformat-into-dd-mm-yy-hhmmss-in-r)

I am reading a date value from csv file.So the format will vary according to the date format of csv. How can I convert any date string to dd-mm-yyy HH:mm:ss ?

```
 The input format are :

  dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss
  dd/mm/yyyy
  dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss
  dd-mm-yyyy
  mm-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss
  mm-dd-yyyy
  mm/dd/yyyy

  yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss
  yyyy-mm-dd
```

I need to convert all these formats to dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss

Comment: How to distinguish between dd-mm-yyyy and mm-dd-yyyy ??

Comment: If the answer to your previous question wasn't sufficient, please edit your question and comment on the answer instead of creating a new question.